# What's the difference between VBB and iO?

Tags: obfuscation

What's the difference between the definitions of virtual black-box (VBB) obfuscation and indistinguishability obfuscation (iO)? Is there any presentation describing both? Furthermore, why is the notion of iO interesting (and sufficient in practical sense) given that it is a weaker notion than VBB?

Comment: [How to Use Indistinguishability Obfuscation](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/454) by Sahai & Waters might be a nice place to start, at least to answer your second question. A classic use of VBB is to convert a symmetric-key encryption into a public-key one (the public key is just a VBB obfuscation of the encryption function). The introduction of the Sahai-Waters paper shows a very nice high-level idea of how to convert symmetric-key to public-key encryption, using only iO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBB is stronger, it states that accessing the (VBB obfuscated) representation is no better than looking at outputs and inputs.

VBB is also impossible in general case, meaning there exist functions that can not be obfuscated.
The nonexistence of general VBB obfuscator doesn't mean VBB obfuscation is impossible as such. It merely means that such a theoretical obfuscator is not polynomial, or it can only work on a subclass of circuits.

Since VBB is stronger than iO, there are some tasks that can be achieved using VBB and cannot be using iO. One such thing is upgrading a symmetric cipher to a homomorphic cipher. You could prepare a circuit that decrypts some message (with hardcoced key), performs an operation and encrypts it again. Then you treat it with VBB.

iO will not work in such arrangement and you will be able to extract the hardcoded key from the obfuscated circuit. It could work however if you somehow obtained a VBB obfuscator magically.

Comment: Why iO does not work in your example? I mean there is universal proxy re-encryption (https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/451.pdf, page 18), where the authors use (probabilistic) iO in order to decrypt and  re-encrypt the ciphertext under a different key. Of course this is in public-key setting. But in your example you consider symmetric encryption and performing computation on plaintext, so is the issue symmetric encryption or performing computation, or both? Can you please elaborate a bit more on your example?

Comment: There is an impossibility result, that there is no obfuscator that could upgrade symmetric cipher to homomorphic cipher, and also symmetric cipher to public cipher.